# Fibonacci Recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, code-snippets

Alright, so I've tried to search for it, and yes, I found the answer, but not the explanation of it, I'd like to know the explanation of the following result:

```
 float fib(int num)
    {
      float  result;

      if (num==1)
         result=0;
      else
          {
        if (num==2)
            result=1;
        else
            result=fib(num-1)+fib(num-2);
          }

      return result;
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're actually asking.  Can you be more precise about what aspect you don't understand?

Comment: Did you look for the definition of the Fibonacci sequence? Notice any similarities between that and the code? Not that it's a nice implementation, in various ways, but...

Comment: @Edward, here's a youtube video for you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrCX8RBVqtU

Comment: You need to provide more detail such as whether you are looking for help on the algorithm or the implementation. Also what do you understand about it now?

Comment: Your question is too general. You should ask for an explanation of something specific. What part do you not understand?

Comment: @Filip thanks, the video helped me!

Comment: Voted to reopen because there is a perfect answer for this question, which Filip provided.  We don't need to put off new people who are interested in a bit of math and programming ... we should encourage it and give him a chance to clarify his question if there's a problem with it.  In this case, I don't think it is "not a real question"; asking for an explanation of how an algorithm for producing the Fibonacci sequence works is a common question - particularly if it involves recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion
Then go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibbonaci_Series

Answer (score 2):

The method called fib() calls itself in certain cases, and does not call itself in other cases (known as base cases).